# Meaning of "You were/are right to take the job"

Tags: meaning

> You were/are right to take the job.

What does this sentence mean?

1. By taking the job, you made a right decision.
2. You were/are qualified to take the job.
3. Either 1 or 2 according to context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has the first meaning: that taking the job was a "right" decision (a good one). "Right" followed by an infinitive verb is an adjective phrase which describes correctness of that action. "You were right to ask this question."

The second meaning would be for "You were right **for** the job."